# jQuery - Detect TD ID on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a TD ID when I'm clicking on a table's row.

I've searched for ways to realize this, and found a way. But everytime I'm clicking, an alert pops up but it's an empty text. Using the console I saw that's the error code is "undefined".

Here's my code :

```
function chooseCell() {
let square = 0;
let squareNumber = 0;
$("td").click((e) => {
    let data = $(this).attr('id');
    alert (data);
    for (square in squarePositions) {
            squareNumber += 1;
            if (square[1] <= e.pageX <= square[3] && square[0] <= e.pageY <= square[2]) {
                alert(squareNumber);
                alert("Square Number : " + squareNumber);

            }
        }
    }
)}
```

If I replace the alert(data) by :

```
alert($('td').attr('id'));
```

The alert pops up the first table's TD. Whenever I click on a different TD, the first ID is displayed

Does someone know how to display the current clicked id ? There were no answers for my problem on Google and SOF

Thank you very much, best regards.

Comment: Please show the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an arrow function for your event handler.

> An arrow function does not newly define its own this when it's being
>   executed in the global context; instead, the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used, equivalent to treating this as
>   closure value.

```
$("td").click((e) => {
    let data = $(this).attr('id');
    alert (data);
     // ...
});
```

Hence in your code `this` doesn't refer to the `td` as you expect it to.
You can use the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to access the `td` with the following code

```
let data = $(e.target).attr('id');
```

Or you can also use a regular function instead of the arrow function and now `this` would refer `td`

```
$("td").click(function(e){
    let data = $(this).attr('id');
    alert (data);
     // ...
});
```