# Select hidden input inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select value from a hidden input inside a td and using this jQuery, but it hasn't worked:

```
 $('.job-detail').click(() => {
   alert($(this).find('input[name=id]').val());
 });

<tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="..." />1</td>
    <td><input class="name" type="hidden"
        value="..." ></td>
    <td>every day 1:00</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="..." />2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>every day 1 hour</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone help me please :D Btw, I can not understand clearly 'this' of jQuery until now :(

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478312/jquery-detect-td-id-on-click/49478670#49478670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to normal function expression instead of [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), when you want to use `this` as it does not have its own **this** and it lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context (scope in which the function was declared)

```
 $('.job-detail').click(function(){
   alert($(this).find('input[name=id]').val());
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But why we shouldn't use arrow function?

Comment: Nguyen, when you use arrow functions, `this` refers to the scope where the function was declared, not the scope of the arrow function itself.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks for your supporting

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrow function but you can't use this keyword inside it, Below is the code which uses arrow function

```
 $('.job-detail').click((e) => {
   alert($(e.currentTarget).find("input[name=id]").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is your arrow function.
Either replace it with a 'normal' function or use the arguments of the click function.

To read more about the different types of functions have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939130/9356258)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid you should add `tr` into a `table` tag, Also run your JS inside `$(document).ready` to make sure DOM object is loaded.

And for `this` it will refer to curent `tr` you click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.job-detail').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="111" />1</td>
    <td><input class="name" type="hidden" value="..."></td>
    <td>every day 1:00</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="222" />2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>every da 1 hour</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.closest` and `.find` selectors are complements of each other and used together are the best way to get to the corresponding element of where the click (or any event) occurred [link](https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq/jquery-find-and-closest-are-your-best-friends).

```js
$('.job-detail').click((e) => {
   alert($(event.target).closest('tr.job-detail').find('input[type=hidden]').val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="..." />1</td>
    <td><input class="name" type="hidden"
        value="..." ></td>
    <td>every day 1:00</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-detail">
    <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="..." />2</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>every day 1 hour</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
    <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
</tr></table>
```